# How do I return a pointer to an array from my function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Sorry there are many similar questions but I just can't work out what I'm doing wrong (amateur alert!).

I'm trying to fill two arrays within a function then get the information back in main. I declare the arrays in main but need to assign them memory in the function (which works out how big they should be). Although the arrays seem to fill fine and I can print them from within the function, I get a segmentation fault when I try to print them from main.

I've tried to troubleshoot in this simplified program with a function that fills one array - it has the same problem. I assume I'm stuffing up my pointers - what am I doing wrong?? Here is the code and the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void *make_v(double num, double *v)
{
        int i;
        v = (double *)calloc(5,sizeof(double));
        for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
                num += 5;
                v[i] = num;
        }

        printf("IN: ");
        for (i=0; i<5; i++)
                printf("%lf ", v[i]);
        printf("\n");
}

main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        double *v=NULL;
        double num=10.0;
        int i;

        make_v(num, v);

        printf("OUT:\nv:[");
        for (i=0; i<5; ++i) {
                printf("%lf ", v[i]);
        }
}
```

This outputs: 
IN: 15.000000 20.000000 25.000000 30.000000 35.000000
OUT:
Segmentation fault

I'm coding in linux if that makes a difference...

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: I would change make_v to return a double *, and then return v at the end. Get rid of the second parameter.

Comment: If you pass in a `double *` pointer you can change what is in the location it points to but you can't change where it points because the address is passed by value.  If you want to update where it points you need to pass a `double **` like this: `void make_v(double num, double **v){...} int main(){... double *v=NULL; ... make_v(num, &v); ... }`

Comment: Do not cast the result of `calloc` & friends or `void *` in general. And don't use `void *` without need!

Comment: Hi JerryJeremiah - sorry to be thick, I follow you so far but how do I alloc and fill v in the function now?

Comment: Hi Bruceg - yes that would be neater but this is a troubleshooting function. My real function has 6 parameters, fills two arrays and returns an int... so that's not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Don't worry, I worked it out! For any other hapless newbies, I assigned memory in the function as before but to *v; then to print used (*v)[i]. Happy happy Kate. Thankyou everyone for helping so quickly

Answer (score 0):

```
double *make_v(double num)
{
    int i;
    v = (double *)calloc(5,sizeof(double));
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
            num += 5;
            v[i] = num;
    }

    printf("IN: ");
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
            printf("%lf ", v[i]);
    printf("\n");
    retrun v;
}
```